# Why does my broken Firefox slow down Windows?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, laptop, 64-bit

I have a strange issue: When I launch Firefox 12 nothing happen and Windows becomes very very slow, only the explorer. For example, when I hover the mouse over the task bar the tool tip takes 1 second to appear, and opening start menu takes also long time.

But, if you switch to a running application (Chrome for example), it is responding properly, and you can open a website and interact with it. After a while (about 15 minutes) suddenly Firefox starts, and Windows gets normal.

I tried to scan for viruses with no luck, I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials.

I tried to run Firefox in safe mode also with no luck.

### Edit:

- I tried to update to v13.
- I tried to delete the profile and created new one, disabling all the extensions.

Doesn't solve anything! Can anyone guide me how to figure out if there is a trojan or spyware?

Comment: Have you tried a) disabling any Firefox extensions you may have installed or b) uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox itself?

Comment: Update Firefox.  If that doesn't work nuke your Firefox profile.

Comment: I tried to disable all extensions, but I think running firefox in safe mode does that automatically

Comment: @Ramhound how do I nuke my firefox profile ??

Comment: See here: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: Try followinf things:
1. Run is safe mode
2. Reinstall firefox
3. Remove all extensions
4. Are you on "Stable" release channel?
5. Clear all the data(history, cookies, temp files) using CCleaner or something else.
6. Reset profile

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, it turned out that Babylon translator is the problem,
I don't know how it is doing it, but even if I removed firefox, deleted all the data and profile files, babylon still can plug itself into firefox again after installation, and make it hang, and make the PC slower.

I used the process monitor, to see what is going on when I start firefox, and I saw babylon starts a lot of activites ( like modifying a file in firefox folders ).